# ListView content not shown using SimpleCursorAdapter unless i click/tap on list item

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am facing a strange problem while populating a `ListView` using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, My source code for `ListFragment` is given below.

***THE PROBLEM: *** after adding some data in the list via my `addEditTaskActivity` (i have tested that there is nothing wrong with insertion.) the content of the `ListView` is not show. But when i click/tap on the List Item the correct data is shown.

I don't know what i am doing wrong here.

***TasksListFragment.java***

```
public class CourseTaskListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {

private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
private ListView mListView;
protected int dialogOkCancel;
protected long selectedTID;
private CursorLoader mCursorLoader;
private AsyncQueryHandler mAsyncQueryHandler;
private Cursor mCursor;
private Context context;
private long semesterID_FK;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mSimpleTaskListAdapter;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

public CourseTaskListFragment(Context context, long currentCourseId,
        long semesterID_FK) {
    super();
    this.currentCourseId = currentCourseId;
    this.semesterID_FK = semesterID_FK;
    this.context = context;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(StudyManagerDataSource.LOG_TAG,
            "TaskListFragment onCreate called!");
    // Enable the option menu for the Fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    setRetainInstance(true);


    mSimpleTaskListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { Task.COL_NAME },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
            SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setListAdapter(mSimpleTaskListAdapter);

    mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    mLoaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);

} // end onCreate

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.course_task_fragment, container, false);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setLongClickable(true);

    registerForContextMenu(mListView);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Task.CONTENT_URI,
            Task.allColumns, Task.COL_COURSE_ID_FK + " = ? and "
                    + Task.COL_SEMESTER_ID_FK + " = ? ", new String[] {
                    String.valueOf(currentCourseId),
                    String.valueOf(semesterID_FK) }, null);

    return mCursorLoader;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mSimpleTaskListAdapter != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        mSimpleTaskListAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    } else {

    }

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    if (mSimpleTaskListAdapter != null)
        mSimpleTaskListAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }


}
```

and the source code of my layout is:

***course_task_fragment.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        style="@style/emptyListMessage"
        android:text="@string/no_homework" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *the content of the ListView is not show* - you see the rows with no content or there is no content at all?

Comment: Where is your `onClickListener` code?

Comment: @Luksprog the content of the list item is only show when it is in selected state. i.e, when i tap on it the content is shown...

Comment: @Sean 'onListItemClick' was unnecessary so i have removed it while posint the question... however nothing is done in that method

Comment: Change the color for the row layout text(what context do you pass to the fragment?). Also the way you coded the fragment class is bad. Never implement constructors for fragment classes because that would bring you problems when the system will try to interact with them. The fragment already has a reference to the `Context` with `getActivity()`. The other variables should be passed in a `Bundle` with `setArguments()`.

Comment: `context` is the context of parent activity that is containing that fragment.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that both the Cursor and the CursorLoader are trying to be observers? Try replacing `SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER` with `0`.

Comment: ohhhhhh... thanks @Luksprog `context` was the problem... `getactivity()` worked for me. Please add your comment in the answer... and i will accept it.

And thanks @Sean for your kind response and precious time.

Comment: and @Luksprog please add description about why it is bad to implement fragment constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Fragment` already has a reference to a `Context`(the `Activity` where is used) which can be retrieved with a call to `getActivity()`. You should use that method to initialize your adapter instance.

Related to your implementation:

You should avoid implementing an arguments constructor like you did. The reason for this is that the Android system might try to recreate your fragment at a later point(in a `ViewPager`, after a configuration change etc) and it will do that by calling the no arguments constructor(which is not implemented in your case). You'll also lose the data values that you passed in.

You don't need to pass the `Context`, the rest you can pass in a `Bundle` as arguments:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.put("course_id", long currentCourseId);
args.put("semester", long semesterID_FK);
// pass this to the fragment instance instead of the constructor
CourseTaskListFragment fragment = new CourseTaskListFragment(); // your current constructor would be removed
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

In the fragment you could then use:

```
getArguments().getLong("couser_id");
getArguments().getLong("semester");
```

to get the values.